# БЭМ Не актуальная документация

Tags: javascript, бэм

[Документация](https://ru.bem.info/platform/bem-xjst/templates-syntax/#block) по синтаксису шаблонов, шаблонизатора bem-xjst, предикаты. К первому подпредикату показан и объяснен пример, который не работает.

неРаботу примера в песочнице можно посмотреть [тут](https://bem.github.io/bem-xjst/?template=block(%27link%27)%3B&bemjson=(%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%20%60true%60%20%D0%B8%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20block%3A%20%27link%27%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%20%60false%60%20%D0%B8%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20block%3A%20%27para%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%27link%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%20block%3A%20%27link%27%2C%20elem%3A%20%27text%27%20%7D%0A%5D)%3B%0A). Комментарий "*// на все следующие сущности предикат вернет `false` и шаблон не будет применён*" объясняет, как должно работать.

В песочнице пробовал все версии шаблонизатора, результат не меняется.

Вопрос: **Где я ошибся?**

Comment: я не думаю что этой штукой кто-топользуется за пределами яндекса, видимо вам надо поискать какой-нибудь прилагающийся форум-репозиторий, здесь ответ услышать маловероятно

Comment: Вопрос лучше задать на форуме bem.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подпредикат - это не фильтр, а по аналогии с CSS - селектор, за которым следует тело шаблона.